# Why does the migration file in Entity Framework have no code inside the up() and down() methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create a new migration using the name `InitialModel`. However, when I open up the migration file, I can only see empty `up()` and `down()` methods. There should be `createTable()` methods within the `up()` method. I have removed migrations, updated the database and started a new project, however, none of these worked. Can someone please tell me how I can get the migration files to display the `createTable` methods?

```
public partial class initialModel : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

[Print screen of up() and down() methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olwSA.png)

[Print screen of DbContext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgClW.png)

Comment: What does your DbContext implementation look like?

Comment: What do you mean "updated the database". Migrations are code first - create your classes and add `DbSets` in your context.

Comment: I have added the context to the model's folder, however, it is not accepting the code. I have just added the print screenshots above in the question. I have added a new file in the models folder called "applicationDbContect.cs with this code " public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; } public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; } public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; } public DbSet<MembershipType> MembershipTypes { get; set; }" However, there is a red squiggly line beneath the extended class "IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>" saying that the namespace could not be found. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by enabling the authentication option at the beginning. This creates a model called IdentityModel.cs which has the code for creating the methods in the up() and down() methods.

[Print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cggoc.png)